# Coherence Cache setting dirty flag

Tags: oracle-coherence

How to set dirty flag for an only few entity in coherence cache. So, cache will load it back in the background or after sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't arbitrarily have the cache refresh a sub-set of entities.

The only thing that comes close to what you describe is [refresh-ahead caching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22837/cache_rtwtwbra.htm#CHDGFFIA), which will refresh entries before they expire if they are being accessed.  If not they will expire and be reloaded on the next get.

If this doesn't meet your needs you'll need to have another process perform the updates for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help it is really useful.                     But as per http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14447_01/coh.330/coh33ug/readthroughwritethrough.htm                                                         Refresh-ahead offers reduced latency compared to read-through, but only if the cache can accurately predict which cache items are likely to be needed in future.                                                               So, how can cache predict which items are most likely to be refreshed without user telling it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe it predicts based on past usage - heavily used items are more likely to be used again and are therefore kept in the cache, however this is obviously down to your particular use case.